# Trying to figure out to equate values in two arrays in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, variables

I am trying to get the output at the end when you enter the number for the word that would match already stored in the array. It currently just spits out the number twice.

```
puts "Welcome to the number-word machine app."

word = []

4.times do
  puts "Enter a word:"
  word << gets.chomp
end


x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x = word

puts "enter a number:"
number = word
word = gets.chomp
puts word
```

Comment: What is expected output, and what is current output?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Expected output should be the word that matches the value. So lets say you put in four words, "car" "cat" "coal" "call" in that order and then enter the number 1, you should get "car".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are over-writing your `word` variable. You should pay careful attention to how you name your variables.

```
puts "Welcome to the number-word machine app."

words = []

4.times do
  puts "Enter a word:"
  words << gets.chomp
end

puts "Enter a number:"
number = gets.chomp

puts "You entered #{number}, which corresponds to:"
puts words[number.to_i]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use one descriptive name for each variable. This makes it more clear what you're trying to do.

Before you were naming the number your user entered `word`, which is confusing. Instead, consider naming it `number`.

Finally, to return the word in your array referenced by the index of the entered number, do `puts words[number]`.

Try this:

```
puts "Welcome to the number-word machine app."

words = []

4.times do
  puts "Enter a word:"
  words << gets.chomp
end

puts "Enter a number:"
number = gets.to_i
puts words[number]
```

Comment: That also produces an error, because `words[number]` is array lookup with a string index: `words["1"]` (`gets.chomp` is a string).

Comment: @BalinKingOfMoria Explanation added. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: @spejamcher I didn't downvote, but I figured someone did because of that (and now you got an upvote). Glad it helped!